# Dell Perc 6/i Raid Monitoring on Linux 2.6.32-2x kernels

Tags: linux, raid, perc6, lsi, dell-perc

I am running an LSI raid (Dell Perc 6/i) on my Ubuntu 10.04 server. I want to monitor the raid array but it seems that there is no software for it. The raid drivers are part of the kernel, but I dont see any tools for it. Software that is available, including LSI's own software, does not work.

Are there any FOSS tools to that I can use to monitor LSI raid arrays?
What is available and supported?

Answer (score 3):

Give [OMSA](http://linux.dell.com/wiki/index.php/Repository/OMSA) a go.  You'll be able to monitor your raid status as well as other server parameters such as memory errors, temperature, etc.

Aditionally if you're integrating this in any FLOSS monitoring tool (Nagios, Hobbit, ...) there are existing plugins as well.

Comment: That link is dead.

Comment: I've fixed the link.

Answer (score 1):

Try MegaCLI.

http://hwraid.le-vert.net/wiki/DebianPackages

Comment: Worked well for me. TY